# Opencart 2.3.0.2 Category foreach products as product clone without limit

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am not sure if this is possible but I am trying to show my products twice on the category.tpl, once as standard with the limit and pagination. The other so it just shows every single product in that category that is on special offer no limits or paginations.

I plan to have a tab / accordion style where you can click to see all products (limited to 10 per page with multiple pages) or all products on the one page that are on special offer (no limits).

There are possibly ways of doing this by filter but I would really like to get it to work separately within the category.php (controller). Or better still if I could get it to work together with the current array the products use (not sure if that would be possible to differentiate).

So far I have tried cloning the products data array in the controller to try and make it work on it's own without limit - the closest I can get is where it only shows the products on special offer from the current pagination.

Here is what I've got at the moment (currently php error message: Undefined index: special - from the category.tpl if statement):

Category.php (controller)

```
$data['specials'] = array();

$filter_specials = array(
'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
'filter_filter'      => $filter,
'sort'               => $sort,
'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit * 0,
'limit'              => 10000
);

$specials = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_specials);    

foreach ($specials as $result) {
$data['specials'][] = array(
'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
'name'        => $result['name'],
'price'       => $price,
'special'     => $special,
 );
}
```

I have tried to mimic the results as result that the products use in the category.php.

Category.tpl:

```
<?php foreach ($specials as $product) { ?>
<?php if ($product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: there is syntax error in your controller code near foreach loop, it should throw fatal error even before going to template.

Comment: @RahulVerma Thanks for replying - that was a copy and paste mistake, on my version there wasn't that error.

Comment: I tried your code at my side, it is not throwing any error.
Are you using only mentioned code in Category.tpl?

Comment: It was to do with $special, I was missing the $special code " if ((float)$result['special']) ... " in the controller. So $special was giving me false rather than a value. Thanks for looking into it and your time!